# How do I create a JS object with keys from two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays, one is dates and the other is prices. I need to create one JS object containing the intersection of these two.

It needs to look like this:

```
{ date: "2018-01-01", price: 82 }
```

or

```
{ date: date[0], price: price[0]}
```

... for 250 rows.

I know that I can use Object.assign.apply to combine objects, but then I got an object looking like:

```
{"2018-01-01": 82 }
```

without the keys. So how do I format the keys?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your arrays are the same length, which I assume they are then you can just iterate over them and add both elements into an object array.

```
let output = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arrLen; i++){
  output.push({
    date: arr1[i],
    price: arr2[i]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `.map()` it and `...` spread it to combine like:

```js
let dates = [{date:'20-jan-2017'},{date:'20-dec-2016'}];
let prices = [{price:200}, {price:300}]

let combined = dates.map((date, key) => { return {...date, ...prices[key]}})

console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both arrays have the same size you could do

```
const prices = [...] // an existing array
const dates = [...] // another array with the same length
const newArray = dates.map((date, i) => ({ date, price: prices[i] }))
```